# How to set auto increment id in hibernate without using annotations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I wanted to set auto increment id while sending data to the database.

I can do so by using annotations `@Id` and `@generatedvalue`. But I don't want that to use annotations.

Are there other ways to do achieve this?

Comment: And why do you not want to use annotations? There are ways but why?

Comment: You can try to configure it via xml but this approach is deprecated, I think you shouldn't avoid using `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue` annotation because those annotation are used for other stuff than only increment in database.

Comment: you can make the db perform the autoincrement

Comment: I think its good to learn every way right bro...So i am trying to learn.By the way thanks for your suggestion....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a sequence in your database and xml config define it as

```
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="id">
    <generator class="sequence">
      <param name="sequence">tracks_seq</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<id name="employeeId" column="EMPLOYEE_ID">
    <generator class="increment"/>
</id>
```